# SLURM srun not running MPI jobs in parallel Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, openmpi, slurm

I can't seem to run MPI jobs using slurm. Any help or advice?

Running a local home based mini cluster to use all of my processors. I'm using 18.04, and have installed the stock openmpi and slurm packages. I have a small test program that I use to show which cores I'm running on. When I run with mpirun I get:

```
$ mpirun -N 3 MPI_Hello
Process 1 on ubuntu18.davidcarter.ca, out of 3
Process 2 on ubuntu18.davidcarter.ca, out of 3
Process 0 on ubuntu18.davidcarter.ca, out of 3
```

When I run with srun I get:

```
$ srun -n 3 MPI_Hello
Process 0 on ubuntu18.davidcarter.ca, out of 1
Process 0 on ubuntu18.davidcarter.ca, out of 1
Process 0 on ubuntu18.davidcarter.ca, out of 1
```

I've done this many times with different arguments (--mpi=pmi2, --mpi=openmpi, etc) and can confirm that instead of running a job with n parallel threads it runs n single threaded jobs. n times the work with 1/n times the expected resources per job.

This is my test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        int numprocs, rank, namelen;
        char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

        MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

        printf("Process %d on %s, out of %d\n", rank, processor_name, numprocs);

        MPI_Finalize();
}
```

This is my /etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf:

```
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator easy.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
ControlMachine=ubuntu18.davidcarter.ca
#ControlAddr=
#
#MailProg=/bin/mail
MpiDefault=none
MpiParams=ports=12000-12100
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid
#SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmd.pid
#SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root
StateSaveLocation=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmctld
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/affinity
#
#
# TIMERS
#KillWait=30
#MinJobAge=300
#SlurmctldTimeout=120
#SlurmdTimeout=300
#
#
# SCHEDULING
FastSchedule=1
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
#SchedulerPort=7321
SelectType=select/linear
#
#
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
ClusterName=cluster
#JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/linux
#SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
#SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
#
#
# COMPUTE NODES
#NodeName=compute[1-4] Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=2 RealMemory=1900 State=UNKNOWN
#NodeName=compute[1-2] Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=4 RealMemory=3800 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=compute1 Sockets=8 CoresPerSocket=1 RealMemory=7900 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=ubuntu18 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=3 RealMemory=7900 State=UNKNOWN

#
# Partitions
PartitionName=debug Nodes=ubuntu18 Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP OverSubscribe=NO
PartitionName=batch Nodes=compute1 Default=NO MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP OverSubscribe=NO
PartitionName=prod Nodes=compute1,ubuntu18 Default=NO MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP OverSubscribe=NO
```

Comment: How have you configured the slurm installation?

Comment: Is OpenMPI compiled with Slurm support? What is the output of `ompi_info  | grep slurm` ?

Comment: The configuration file is shown in the original posting.<br/>

OpenMPI appears to be compiled with slurm support. This is what I get when I run openmpi_info:<br/>

    dcarter@ubuntu18:~$ ompi_info | grep slurm
                     MCA ess: slurm (MCA v2.1.0, API v3.0.0, Component v2.1.1)
                     MCA plm: slurm (MCA v2.1.0, API v2.0.0, Component v2.1.1)
                     MCA ras: slurm (MCA v2.1.0, API v2.0.0, Component v2.1.1)

Comment: What version of OpenMPI?